# Trouble getting SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach to work with Pydantic: Any Examples?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I am trying to use the [SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach](https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/) with [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) and [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), but not having much success.

I have never used SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach before, and I am sure I am using it wrong.  I cannot seem to save any images, but I can get all non-image aspects working. (I have successfully integrated SQLAlchemy + Pydantic + FastAPI, and there are [also great examples](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) to help.)

---

I am trying to make a DB-backed website where users can create quiz questions and embed images along with the questions, too.  The code below highlights the portions related to the quiz questions + images.

My Pydantic models/schemas:

```py
from typing import List, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class QuestionPictureBase(BaseModel):
    pass


class QuestionPicture(QuestionPictureBase):
    id: int
    question_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class QuestionBase(BaseModel):
    header: str
    details: str


class QuestionCreate(QuestionBase):
    pass


class Question(QuestionBase):
    id: int
    creator_id: int
    pictures: List[QuestionPicture] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

The SQLAlchemy models:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_imageattach.entity import Image, image_attachment

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///sqlalch.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = "questions"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    header = Column(String, index=True)
    details = Column(String, index=True)
    creator_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
*** pictures = image_attachment("QuestionPicture", uselist=True) ***
    creator = relationship("User", back_populates="questions")


class QuestionPicture(Base, Image):
    """Model for pictures associated with the question."""

    __tablename__ = "question_pictures"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Not sure if the question ID should also be a unique identifier
    # question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("questions.id"), primary_key=True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("questions.id"))
    question = relationship("Question", back_populates="pictures")
```

---

The highlighted line

```
*** pictures = image_attachment("QuestionPicture", uselist=True) ***
```

is where I think I am doing things wrong.  But I am not quite sure what I should be doing.

I just don't really get how the `image_attachment` function call should be used.  It just seems to work "automagically" in the SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach docs, and I do not understand it.

Does anyone have any working examples using SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach + Pydantic (+ FastAPI).  It's the interaction with Pydantic that mostly has me confused.

---

#### Update

There was a request for more detail, and there is simply too much to put on a question.  So instead, I created a git branch containing all of the backend, but only the backend, called `temp`, and [pushed it to a public GitHub repo](https://github.com/lazarillo/kids-quizzes/tree/temp/backend/src/sqlalch).

---

## Solution

`@r-m-n`'s solution below got me a good part of the way there, but my main problem was that it was unclear to me what my `pictures` database needed to contain.

After looking at some error output and reading the source code, I found [the needed structure here](https://github.com/dahlia/sqlalchemy-imageattach/blob/b4bafa73f3bb576ecf67ed7b40b702704a0fbdc8/sqlalchemy_imageattach/entity.py#L228) and adjusted my alembic (db versioning) code as follows:

```py
def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        "question_pictures",
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True),
        sa.Column(
            "question_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("questions.id"), nullable=False
        ),
        sa.Column("width", sa.Integer, nullable=False),
        sa.Column("height", sa.Integer, nullable=False),
        #: (:class:`str`) The mimetype of the image
        #: e.g. ``'image/jpeg'``, ``'image/png'``.
        sa.Column("mimetype", sa.String(255), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("original", sa.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False),
        sa.Column("created_at", sa.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
    )
```

Of the list above, it is `width`, `height`, `original`, `mimetype`, and `created_at` that were missing and which I was unaware I needed to add.

(`sa` above is short for `sqlalchemy` and `op` is short for `alembic.op`.)

Comment: I've never worked with SQLAlchemy images too, but do you mind sharing the part where you get the image and fill the pydantic class? From this tutorial https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/api/entity.html it seems that you can use both blob and file, so the error may lie in the way you fill the model's data (just suggesting possible reasons)

Comment: Yes, @lsabi, I can share the whole thing, but I thought it would be too much to grasp for just one question.  I have edited the original question to include a link to a github repo that I created and pushed it to.

Comment: I did not run it, but could it be that using pass in the pydantic model causes some problems when creating a dictionary on line https://github.com/lazarillo/kids-quizzes/blob/temp/backend/src/sqlalch/crud.py#L38 ? What error does the terminal return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach uses `lazy=dynamic` parameter by default when creating a relationship: https://github.com/dahlia/sqlalchemy-imageattach/blob/master/sqlalchemy_imageattach/entity.py#L148. So `question.pictures` returns a `Query` object instead of a list and you need to call `question.pictures.all()` to get the list of pictures.

You can set `lazy=select` or `lazy=joined`. See more about lazy param [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.lazy).

```
pictures = image_attachment("QuestionPicture", uselist=True, lazy='select')
```

Comment: I have tried and I am able to move forward, but still have not gotten everything working.  I have awarded the bounty, so that I do not have to worry about forgetting and letting it expire.  :(  But I will update with an acceptance once I have gotten it all to work.

Comment: I have updated my question with the ultimate solution to my problem, but this answer helped me get close, Thanks!